# Azure CLI doesn't recognize resource group

Tags: azure, azure-cli

So I'm new on Azure and got some problems with the CLI on the portal. After creating an AKS service using the UI, I cannot find it in the CLI and get an error message as shown below. Am I missing an obscure setting that filters resources? I can't even find my resource group.

Checked the spelling multiple times, obv.
Also checked this [Resource not found...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-not-found#solution-3---get-external-resource), which is again for very obscure queries, whereas mine is extremely simple.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
(ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'WebPlatformResource' could not be found.
Code: ResourceGroupNotFound
Message: Resource group 'WebPlatformResource' could not be found.
```

Comment: Could you please let us know if you have multiple subscription

Comment: Yep, though I only use one. But if I understand correctly, a command like `az group list` should work without specifying the subscription?

Comment: We can use this `cmd` to list all subscriptions - `az account list --output table`
 and to set our subscription  -   `az account set --subscription  "My Demos"`

Comment: Guess that did the trick! Weird that overnight it just changed my default subscription.

Comment: That is literally what I'm saying...

Comment: Hello @Niels Uitterdijk , If its helpful Could you please mark it as an answer to help other community members for this type of similar issue. Thank you:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you @Niels Uitterdijk , As discussed i am posting it as an answer to help other community members for the similar issue .

> Message: Resource group 'yourresourcegroup' could not be found.

The above error occurs if we have multiple subscriptions, set your subscription first and then try:

- **To list all subscriptions** -  `az account list --output table`
- **To set your subscription** -    `az account set --subscription "My Demos"`

For more information please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/manage-azure-subscriptions-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) .